# Expected '' to equal 'Changes you made may not be saved.'

Tags: protractor

While running protractor test, getting below error :

✗Login without password(20 s)
Expected '' to equal 'Changes you made may not be saved.'. [stack]

Code is here which I have written in VS Code :

```
 it('Login without password', function () {
    browser.sleep(3000);
    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('login');
    browser.sleep(3000);
    loginPage.loginInput.sendKeys('asd');
    browser.sleep(3000);
    browser.refresh().then(() => null, () => {
        return browser.switchTo().alert().then((alert) => {
            browser.sleep(3000);
            expect(alert.getText()).toEqual('Changes you made may not be saved.');
            browser.sleep(3000);
            alert.accept();
            browser.sleep(3000);
            return loginPage.open();
        });
    });
```

Comment: does that alert actually show? you don't have a ton of info here to distinguish this from a bug or a valid test that's failing.

Comment: Alert is showing the message 'Changes you made may not be saved.'.   I have tried manually also and it is working fine. On the automation part, it is failing.

Comment: Could you attach a screenshot of the alert?

Comment: Pls find attaced SS.